# SQL query can't be executed in Chrome Device tools after updating Chrome

Tags: android, sqlite, google-chrome-devtools

I want to execute SQL query in Chrome DevTools for my application. After updating to Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit), I am unable to execute. Even it doesn't throw the error.

Look over the screenshot enter image description here I have attached here..

[Here, Query cant be executed on pressing enter or any other keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXDWo.png)

[Error or warning is not thrown in case of invalid input/query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOSjO.png)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com if it's not already reported there.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm to guide me

Comment: Same here, it is still not working... Were you able to report it Naisargi? Thanks, Federico.

Comment: @FedericoAlvarez I mention bug tracker link, according to them, this issue should report to stetho. 

[link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929636&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=pnaisargi515&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)

Comment: @NaisargiPatel thanks for the update, the issue is also reported on [Stethos Git](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/647)

Comment: Checked that. Thank you @FedericoAlvarez

Comment: @NaisargiPatel [here too...](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/634)

Comment: Yea, this is already mentioned under comments in previously your shared link. @FedericoAlvarez But the point is still there is not any solution available excepting downgrading my version.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Chromium. Worked for me